# Loop and array within and array within an array to get list of variables

Tags: node.js, arrays, loops, for-loop

Need to get a list of all accounts by section and the net total of the debit and credit values.  For example:

Section:Revenue
ACC Income: $10,000
Other Income: $5,000

Section Expenses
Advertising: 100
Rent: 20,000

I have used a for...in loop but only get down to the object of the array.  I know I need to loop within a loop but I don't know how to.  Have been trying for 2wks now and still only get down to the Section, not the accounts and values.

```json
{
    "cashtb": {
        "response": {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": {
            "reports": [
                {
                    "reportID": "TrialBalance",
                    "reportName": "Trial Balance",
                    "reportType": "TrialBalance",
                    "reportTitles": [
                        "Trial Balance",
                        "Test Org",
                        "As at 1 July 2022"
                    ],
                    "reportDate": "27 September 2022",
                    "rows": [
                        {
                            "rowType": "Header",
                            "cells": [
                                {
                                    "value": "Account"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Debit"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Credit"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "YTD Debit"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "YTD Credit"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "rowType": "Section",
                            "title": "Revenue",
                            "rows": [
                                {
                                    "rowType": "Row",
                                    "cells": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "ACC Income (191)",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 09dcab5a-152e-4fc2-a983-b80473b4c9f5"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 09dcab5a-152e-4fc2-a983-b80473b4c9f5"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "0.00",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 09dcab5a-152e-4fc2-a983-b80473b4c9f5"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 09dcab5a-152e-4fc2-a983-b80473b4c9f5"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "13456.25",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 09dcab5a-152e-4fc2-a983-b80473b4c9f5"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowType": "Row",
                                    "cells": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "Eftpos Surcharge Income (193)",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 9bb9b698-1ced-4ae1-9c29-40f372df2be0"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 9bb9b698-1ced-4ae1-9c29-40f372df2be0"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "82.61",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 9bb9b698-1ced-4ae1-9c29-40f372df2be0"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 9bb9b698-1ced-4ae1-9c29-40f372df2be0"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "3304.29",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": 9bb9b698-1ced-4ae1-9c29-40f372df2be0"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowType": "Row",
                                    "cells": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "Subcontractor Income (192)",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e5f36c13-097b-4a01-857a-8400d62ad02d"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e5f36c13-097b-4a01-857a-8400d62ad02d"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "1086.96",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e5f36c13-097b-4a01-857a-8400d62ad02d"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e5f36c13-097b-4a01-857a-8400d62ad02d"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "10088.15",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e5f36c13-097b-4a01-857a-8400d62ad02d"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "rowType": "Section",
                            "title": "Expenses",
                            "rows": [
                                {
                                    "rowType": "Row",
                                    "cells": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "Advertising (301)",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e157460d-76f1-4b34-ac21-b29a9cb446ad"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "0.00",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e157460d-76f1-4b34-ac21-b29a9cb446ad"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e157460d-76f1-4b34-ac21-b29a9cb446ad"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "1968.40",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e157460d-76f1-4b34-ac21-b29a9cb446ad"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": "",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "account",
                                                    "value": e157460d-76f1-4b34-ac21-b29a9cb446ad"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }]}]}]}}}}
```

I used this code but it only goes to sectione and returns row heading but not the values in the object like account or debit/credit values

```
let cellstrip = cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows;
  for(let i=0, len=cellstrip.length; i<len; i++){
    for (let valuestrip in cellstrip[i]){
      console.log(valuestrip, cellstrip[i] 
[valuestrip]);
}
 }
//you can put another loop in here that starts with 
“j” - e.g.
  for(let j=0, len=valuestrip.length; j<len; j++){
    for (let accountsstrip in valuestrip.Rows[0].Cells[cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[k] 
.Rows[l].Cells.length - 3].Value !== ''){
      //Do something which each value
      var accountvalue = accountsstrip;
      console.log(accountvalue);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have, please.

Comment: I used this but it goes to sections and then nothing after that

Comment: A) Please put code in the question, it's really hard to follow in comments. B) Use the triple-backtick method for marking code, not the `>` approach used earlier. C) Please try and keep examples *minimal*. You posted a mountain of JSON.

Comment: Ok I did that thanks